# Checking index through a list of indexes

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have the following list:

```
lst = [['dad','50',1],['brother','20',1],['mom','30',1],['sister','10',1],['dad','50',2],['brother','20',2],['mom','30',2],['sister','10',2]]
```

I am trying to select the family (indicated by 1 or 2) and compare the ages to from family members in the family to find which is the highest.
I was able to distinguish between the families and find the oldest, but I can't print the family member's role because in the process his age is no longer linked into the list with his name.
Below, if the family is the first one, the program should check and compare their age and print out his role in the family.

```
age =[]
for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i][2] == "1": # checking thats its family 1
            age.append(int(lst[i][1])) # creates lists of all ages in fam 1

    m = max(age)
    m = str(m) # finds the oldest
```

From here, I cannot think of a way to link the oldest back to its line so that I can print it. Any help? Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a key function with `max`

```
people =[]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i][2] == "1": # checking thats its family 1
        people.append(lst[i])

eldest = max(people, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
```

`eldest` will contain the complete list of values representing a person in your data structure.

It's also worth noting that your data and code may not be consistent. For instance the 2nd index (family id number) is an integer, but you're testing for membership with a string. Your age is also encoded as a string, which is why my key function casts it to an integer.

Comment: The code I posted was simplified, the actual text file contains 8 different data. I'm not quite sure how I can use your solution with that. Would you mind clearing up the key function max? Cheers

Comment: Sure. When a `key` function is provided for `max`,  that function is called on each item of the iterable given to the `max` function, and the element which maximizes the `key` function is returned. This same mechanism is available for `min` and `sorted`.

Answer (score 0):

You could either (A) store the names with the ages, then you'll just have it on hand when you need it, or you could (B), go back and find the individual who has the age you want. Here's an example of (B):

```
# your for loop
for ...

# outside of your for loop, not inside as your code has it
max_age = max(age)

for person in lst:
    if person[2] == 1 and int(person[1]) == max_age:
        name_of_oldest_person_in_family_1 = person[0]
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a single line as well

```
from itertools import ifilter

lst = ...
oldest = max(ifilter(lambda x: x[2] == 1, lst), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

To "link" the age back to the original list, I would suggest changing the age list to a dictionary:

```
age = {}
```

And in that dictionary you can store the age as the key, and the list it came from as a list. For example, the first dad is 50 years old, and when this data is appended to the age dictionary it would appear as

```
{50 : last[0]}
```

With a dictionary like this it is easy to access the original list.

---

**or...**
What I would highly suggest is creating a class for the family members, and make name and age attributes. You can differentiate the two families with the classes they are defined by. Here's how I would do that:

```
class Family1():
   def __init__(self,name,age):
       self.name = name
       self.age = age

class Family2(Family1):
   def __init__(self,name,age):
       Family1.__init__()

dad1 = Family1("Dad",50)
# etcetera
```